# How do you run a NodeJS app in the background without it ending when you log out?

Tags: ubuntu, service, node.js

I'm trying to keep an application on my ubuntu server running so that Google has time ping it, but the app keeps shutting down when I log out.

I start the Nodejs app with `supervisor` to monitor changes (via a shell script)

I found commands like `nohup`, but I'm really clueless when it comes to running background services other than typing simple commands like `service httpd start` which seems to work pretty well for Apache on CentOS!

Do I need to create another user to run services on? I have a Linode instance with Ubuntu 10.04

**run.sh**

```
cd myapp/src/main/node
supervisor -w "myapp/src/main/node,myapp2/src/main/node,./" run-apps.js
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
nohup supervisor -w "myapp/src/main/node,myapp2/src/main/node,./" run-apps.js &
```

Some other ways:

- [Run Node.js as a Service on
  Ubuntu](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/run_nodejs_as_a_service_on_ubuntu_karmic/)
- [Keep a node.js server up with
  Forever](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever)

Answer (score 5):

The reason it exits is because when you logout and terminate the parent shell, the script receives a HUP signal and loses its ability to write to STDOUT and STDERR.

You have 4 options, (in order of "correctness" and "cleanness"):

1. Modify it so that it ignores a HUP signal and logs cleanly to a file.
2. Run the script in a `screen` session
3. Run the script using `nohup`
4. Create a fairly complex bash script that launches the script then `disown`s it and closes associated STDOUT and STDERR channels.

Comment: Thank you for this! How would I use any of these commands say `nohup` or `screen` with `supervisor` as part of my shell script?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it without `nohup`: disown it.

E.g.:

```
$ jobs
$ sleep 300 &
[1] 79844
$ jobs
[1]  + running    sleep 300
$ disown %1
$ jobs
$ pgrep sleep
79844
```

Explaination:

1. Use `jobs` to show background jobs, there are none
2. Background `sleep 300`
3. Use `jobs` again. PID for `sleep` is 79844 and is job #1
4. Disown job #1
5. Use `jobs` again. No background jobs.
6. Use `pgrep` to find any processes named `sleep`. There is one, with PID 79844 (same PID)

You can close the terminal and/or logout without affecting the disowned job.

This has the advantage of not leaving around a `nohup.out` file, but you also lose anything written to `STDOUT`.